# How do I replace all instances of a dash (-) with a foward slash (/) in a string

Tags: javascript, string

I need your help,

How do I go about replacing all instances of a dash `-` with a forward slash `/` in a string

```
var x = "03-04-2014"
```

After conversion:

```
var x = "03/04/2014"
```

Comment: <del>those arent strings.</del> Anyway, what have you tried? How did it not work? Why did all the functions [you could've found via the search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=replace+dash+slash+[javascript]) not work?

Comment: @Bergi What do you mean are they not string?

Comment: @D.Kasipovic: Before the edit, he left out the quotes and had numeric expressions instead…

Comment: @Bergi Ah I see, thanks for taking the time to clarify, I thought I was missing something.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

with `string.replace`

```
x = x.replace(/\-/g, '/')
```

or split

```
x.split('-').join('/')
```